# Gaussian tail probability

Tags: inequality, normal-distribution, distribution-tails, quantile

Let $z(q)$ be the quantile of a standard normal random variable $Z$, i.e., $z(q) = k$ when $\Pr(Z\geq k) = q$. Then I would like to know why the following two results hold.

(a) If we hold $\alpha$ fixed, then asymptotically
$$
|z(\alpha / n)|=\sqrt{2 \log (n)}\left(1-\frac{\log \log n}{4 n}\right) .
$$
(b) For finite samples, one can use the excellent approximation
$$
|z(\alpha / n)| \approx \sqrt{B\left(1-\frac{\log B}{B}\right)} \text { where } B:=2 \log (n/\alpha  )-\log (2 \pi)
$$

Could someone explain why (a) and (b) hold, or perhaps guide me some references to them? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe something useful here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Numerical_approximations_for_the_normal_CDF_and_normal_quantile_function

Comment: @Blitzer I did not get it yet.